# Is there a way to remove custom designs from the ground?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

While I was half asleep, I had the brilliant idea to make some fancy roads with QR code paths and paste them on the ground. Now, being awake, I realized that I really messed up. After messing around a bit, I noticed that there was no visible way to remove them. Is there a way to remove them?

Comment: Plus one for playing while drowsy regrets . . .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All you have to do is stand on/near the pattern that you have placed and hit the <kbd>Y</kbd> button to pick it up! Thankfully, in this version, they've separated this from the Run button (<kbd>B</kbd>), so you don't have to worry about accidentally picking up paths while running on them anymore.